# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' with Python Format funtion

Tags: python

I am trying to use the Python format function with the following but I keep on getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

df_data.to_csv(r"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{}.txt", index=False).format("test")
```

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
df_data.to_csv(r"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{}.txt".format("test"), index=False)
```

### Error

```py
df_data.to_csv(...) # Returns None And You try to implement format on this like

df_data.to_csv(...).format('test')
```

Comment: this worked, thank you Sharim ```df_data.to_csv(r"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{}.txt".format("test"), index=False)```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your code together and you will be able to spot the problem easily.

```
df_data.to_csv(r"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{}.txt", index=False).format("test")
```

The above code means that your code is trying to transform `df_data` - a dataframe to CSV, while the `to_csv` takes two arguments.

The first argument is the path, you are trying to format the path dynamically, but the format() method should directly follow the string that you try to format, otherwise you are telling the `.format` method to operate on the return value of `to_csv()`, which is **None**, now we can see the problem.

You could refer to the documentation of `to_csv` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv),

Then, the correct way of formatting should be

```
"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{}.txt".format("test")
```

or even simpler using Python 3.6+ f-string syntax

```
f"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{your_variable}.txt"
```

Comment: my suggestion is, you should copy-paste the doc text rather than take a screenshot. and it's better to include a link to the doc you are quoting from. fyi i'm not the one who downvoted.